# SOAP Authentication is not being sent

Tags: wcf, security, authentication, soap

We are in the process of moving some software from our test environment into a production test environment.  We've ran into a problem where our service can't communicate with another 3rd party service.  After a bit of packet sniffing I was able to figure out that when the message is being sent on the working system the POST has an Authorization: Basic  that is missing on the production test environment POST.

The question I have is does anyone know of any likely causes?  The dlls are the exact same.  Configuration has been verified (and in fact there are checks in the code to ensure configuration exists).  At this point it just seems like the SoapHttpProtocol is ignoring the NetworkCredential that we provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the account that the service was using to startup and that seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be related to security zones.

There is a difference between "Trusted Sites" and "Internet" zone, with respect to sending over authentication information.

You could browse the the 3rd party site from the test and production environment and check if the zone settings are the same.

Comment: The security zones don't seem to differ at all but thanks for the idea.